# Issues trying to scale up sine wave in c

Tags: c, trigonometry

Hopefully somebody can point out why this isnt working or where i may be going wrong. Im producing a sine wave by way of for loops in c. The ultimate aim is to produce a .ppm file displaying this. Im working on a 1 to 1 pixel ratio. My box is 128H*256W. The sine wave is displaying but due to the answer being produced in rads the result is a very small two pixel high "wave". I assume this is due to the rad values being between 1 and -1. This is my code. I tried just simply timesing by a greater number to increase the size of the y values in the hopes it would plot correctly but this does little or worse causes the applicattion to stop running. Any ideas very welcome.

```
for (x = 0; x < H; x++)
    {

        y =(int) H/2+ sin(x*(2*PI));
        y = y * 50;
        image[y][x][1] = 0;
        image[y][x][2] = 255;
        image[y][x][3] = 0;
    }
```

EDIT: This is what is being produced in the .ppm file when opened via infraview. Also im #defining PI 3.141592653589793. Again is this possibly an area of issue.

[first sine wave .ppm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBDVW.png)

Comment: You should multiply `y` by 50 before casting to `int`, e.g. `y = (int) (50 * (H / 2 + sin(x * 2 * PI)));`.

Comment: Hi, will this not affect the scale? *50 in order to increase the size of my wav from the 2 pixels its populating now.

Comment: If you want fewer "wave peaks", you need to divide your x by something. Remember that when fed with radians, sin(x) will go from 0, to 1, to 0, to -1 and back to 0, as x goes from 0 to 2*PI. If you want one full sin as x goes from 0 to H, you need to divide x by H*2*PI

Comment: Hi, thanks! I want a more defined first harmonic sine wave to be produced. The number of peaks isnt a huge problem as long as i have at least two. As you mention sin(x) only works in rads andi think thats my issue as my loops, i think, take one pixel to equal one value. I need to scale it so that the values can be between 1 and -1 but will also plot more of the available 128*256 pixels.

Comment: Use `M_PI` from `<math.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

I conject that `y` is an `int`.

Your `sin` value will be truncated to an integer; 0 for most cases, but very occasionally -1 or +1.

The fix is simple: use a floating point for `y`, and cast once you want to use it as an array index.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response! My y is declared as an int globally. I can change it to a float locally and maybe use a different naming convention but my array requires y be an int to work. Could i convert it back?

Comment: Indeed. Use a `double` until you need to use it as an array index. Then cast it. (But check it's a suitable size *before* taking the cast.)

Comment: @superstuck Note: Do not use single-letter names for global variables. More general, avoid global variables whereever possible. `y` should definitively be local.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for the tip, I'm just following that type of naming convention as that how ive previously been taught.

Comment: @superstuck: Then you should get a better tutor.

Comment: @Olaf im starting to think that myself.

Answer (score 0):

`y = y * 50`, where `y = H/2` (+ or - 1) gives you y around `25*H`, which is out of bounds.

A closer approximation is this:

```
y = (int) ( H/2 + H/2 * sin(x*2*PI) )
```

which gives the extremes `H/2 - H/2 = 0` and `H/2 + H/2 = H`, which is one too high. So, we scale not by `H/2` but by `(H-1)/2`:

```
y = (int) ( H/2 + (H-1)/2 * sin(x*2*PI) )
```

which gives us an y-range `0` to `H-1`.

To have a bit more control over the period of the sine wave, let's write it like this:

```
sin( x/W * 2*PI )
```

Here, we divide `x` by `W` so that `x/W` itself will range from 0 to 1.
It is then scaled by `2*PI` to produce a range from 0 to 2π. This will plot one period of the sine wave across the entire width. If we introduce a frequency factor `f`:

```
sin( f * x/W * 2*PI )
```

we can now say how many periods to draw, even fractions. For `f=1` it will draw one period, `f=2` two periods, and `f=1` half a period.

Here's a small JS demo showing three values for `f`: `0.5` is red, `1` is green and `2` is white:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c'),
    W = c.width,
    H = c.height,
    ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
    image = ctx.getImageData(0,0,W,H);

for ( var i = 0; i < image.data.length; i +=4) {
 image.data[i+0]=0;
 image.data[i+1]=0;
 image.data[i+2]=0;
 image.data[i+3]=255;
}  



function render(image,colidx,f) {
  for ( var x = 0; x < W; x++ )
  {
    var y = H/2 - Math.round( H/2 * Math.sin(f*x/W*Math.PI*2) );
    if ( y >=0 && y < H ) {
      if ( colidx & 1 ) image.data[ 4*( W*y + x ) + 0] = 255;
      if ( colidx & 2 ) image.data[ 4*( W*y + x ) + 1] = 255;
      if ( colidx & 4 ) image.data[ 4*( W*y + x ) + 2] = 255;      
    }
  }
}
  
render(image,1,0.5);
render(image,2,1);
render(image,7,2);

ctx.putImageData(image, 0,0);
```

```css
canvas{ border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id='c' width='256' height='128'></canvas>
```

The code then becomes:

```
float f = 1;
for (x = 0; x < W; x++)
{
    y = (int) ( (H-1)/2 + (H-1)/2 * sin(f * x/W * 2*PI) );
    image[y][x][0] = 0;
    image[y][x][1] = 255;
    image[y][x][2] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Kenney, i think youre correct about needing to take one from H as my  axis has an additional pixel at the top right. My Y axis has a step in it about quarter of the way along so im not sure the loop is running from the correct point.

Comment: Your main problem was `y *= 50` as I said in the first line, not whether `y` is an `int`. Your `y` starts at about `25*H`, which is an overflow by a factor of 25, causing an x-offset. Tried my code yet? Otherwise, try to loop x from 0 to 10 to see that your graph starts about about 20-25% from the left into the image.

Comment: the first thing i did was remove the y*=50 as this was just a shot in the dark. I have tried you code and it gives simlar results to mine in that it doesnt create a full wave. Again i think the issue is how pi is working and how rads are being converted to the .ppm. If rads only work between 1 and -1 then theres only going to be two pixels difference. This is the issue i cannot get around. i believe some students have started using negative fractions etc to get to work but i dont really understand this approach or how to apply it.

Comment: You are iterating x from 0 to W where W is 256 or `image` width? How is `image` defined, like `unsigned char image[H][W][3]`? Also, rads are the `sin` input, from 0 to 2PI, which means from 0 to 360 degrees; incrementing x should give you around 6 points per sine wave, enough to recognize it. You can do `sin( x * 2*PI / 10)` to get a wider wave, but, you should first get it to draw over the full width of the image. How does the image look now?

Comment: image is defined as an int image[y][x][3]. W is the image width which should be the number of pixels displayed in the .ppm file. It is drwing the line the full width, my original code was also doing that, its the height that im not getting that i want. I only need it to complete 2 full waves.

Comment: Added some more explanation on how to do that, and a JS demo. Tested the code and it produces `y` values from `0` to `127`, nicely centered around `64`.

Answer (score 0):

As `y` is [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225459/issues-trying-to-scale-up-sine-wave-in-c/34226020#comment56195173_34225527) to be an `int` and `H` appears to be an `int` constant, perform calculations as `double` first, then convert to `int`.

Use `round` to avoid truncations effect of simply casting a `double` to `int`.

```
y = (int) round(50*(sin(x*(2*PI)) + H/2.0));
```

Original code also scaled `H/2` by 50.  I think code may only want to scale the `sin()` and not the offset.

```
#define XOffset 0
#define YOffset (H/2.0)
#define XScale (2*PI)
#define YScale 50
y = (int) round(YScale*sin(x*XScale + XOffset) + YOffset);
```

Defensive programming tip: since `y` is calculated, insure it is in the valid index range before using it as an index.

```
// Assuming image` is a fixed sized array
#define Y_MAX (sizeof image/sizeof image[0] - 1)
if (y >= 0 && y <= Y_MAX) { 
  image[y][x][1] = 0;
  image[y][x][2] = 255;
  image[y][x][3] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the assitance. My main issue at the moment is that y isnt being plotted enough. its missing some points when i am able to scale it up and is just coming off looking like a series of rows of dashes as opposed to an actual wave, Is this due to the truncation issue possibly?

Comment: @superstuck The `XScale` is likely coarse.  Try `#define XScale (2*PI/64.0)`

Comment: i tried this and it did seem to produce a wider x value. how could implement someting simlar to increase the y?

Comment: @superstuck to increase `y` try different values for `YScale` like `#define YScale 75`